# split list into lists each of length x

Tags: r, list, split, purrr

Simple problem, given a list:

```
main_list <- list(1:3,
                  4:6,
                  7:9,
                  10:12,
                  13:15)
main_list
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6

# [[3]]
# [1] 7 8 9

# [[4]]
# [1] 10 11 12

# [[5]]
# [1] 13 14 15
```

I want to split the list into multiple lists where I break up the original one into lists each of length `x`. So if I said `x = 2`, I would get 3 lists of length 2, 2 and the leftover 1:

```
target <- list(list(1:3,
               4:6),
               list(7:9,
               10:12),
               list(13:15))
target
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3

# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 4 5 6


# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 7 8 9

# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 10 11 12


# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1] 13 14 15
```

Something like:

```
my_split <- function(listtest, x) {
  split(listtest, c(1:x))
  }
target <- my_split(main_list, 2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an option with `gl`

```
split(main_list, as.integer(gl(length(main_list), 2, length(main_list))))
```

It can be converted to a custom function

```
f1 <- function(lstA, n) {
      l1 < length(lstA)
      split(lstA, as.integer(gl(l1, n, l1)))
  }
```

Comment: I've never used `gl`. Probably never will, but it's fun to know it exists.

Comment: @IanCampbell I had used it before.  Mostly it comes under the post where `%/%` is used for splitting

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: no conditional logic needed. Just use `split()` with `c()` and `rep()`:

```
my_split <- function(l, x){

  l_length <- length(l)
  l_div <- l_length / x

  split(l, c(rep(seq_len(l_div), each = x), rep(ceiling(l_div), l_length %% x)))

}

my_split(main_list, 2)
```